# Questions about bash

Tags: bash

Firstly, I'm wondering how to input information from the terminal into a variable in the script file. For example, lets say I wanted to do ./name.sh dave in the terminal instead of using read -p to ask for the name in the script. Secondly, I'm wondering how to go about creating a new directory and then copying files into that directory. I know how to use the mkdir command, but not how to copy files to that new directory.

Sorry if my wording is a bit bad I wasn't sure how else to ask the questions (this is my first day messing with bash.)

Comment: Click the [tag:bash] tag, then click "Learn more..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run:

```
./name.sh dave
```

the string `dave` will be the first positional argument in the script.  You can access it with `$1`.  To create a directory named `dave` and copy files into it, you might do:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=${1:?}
mkdir "$dir" || exit
cp * "$dir"
```

A few things are a bit cryptic, and perhaps you might prefer:

```
#!/bin/sh
if test -z "$1"; then
    echo "Parameter missing" >&2;
    exit 1
fi
mkdir "$1" && cp * "$1"
```

Basically, you access the parameters via `$1`, `$2`, etc.  The `${1:?}` syntax is a shortcut that assigns the variable `dir`, but aborts the script if `$1` is unset or empty.  (eg, if you call the script without an argument.)

The rest seems pretty self-explanatory.

Suppose you wanted to specify the files to copy, so that `./name.sh dave` would create a directory named `dave` and copy all files in the current directory to it (as above), but if you pass more arguments it would copy only those files.  In that case, you might do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=${1:?}
shift  # Discard the first argument, shift remaining down
mkdir "$dir" || exit

case $# in
0) cp * "$dir";;
*) cp "$@" "$dir";;
esac
```

Here, `"$@"` is the list of each argument, individually quoted.  (eg, if you call the script with an argument that has spaces, it will properly pass that argument to cp.  Compare that with `cp $@ $dir` or `cp "$*" $dir`.)  If you're just starting with shell scripts, I would advise you always be careful about quotes.